# Filter a table of json files in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file which contains a table of jsons. I want to filter the information inside that table. My table is look like:

```
         {    
         "Item_Weight_Process1":[
                     {
                              "Timestamp": "131563265.81",
                              "Item_Weight_Process1_values": 0.4,
                              "Performance":0.8
                      },
                         {
                             "Timestamp": "132563265.81",
                             "Sla_Weight_Process1_Values": 0.4,
                             "Performance": 1
                         },
                         {
                             "Timestamp": "133563265.81",
                             "Item_Weight_Process1_values": 0.4,
                             "Performance": 1
                         },
                         {
                             "Timestamp": "134563265.81",
                             "Item_Weight_Process1_values": 0.5,
                             "Performance": 1
                         },
                         {
                             "Timestamp": "1355463265.81",
                             "Item_Weight_Process1_values": 0.3,
                             "Performance": 1
                         },
                         {
                             "Timestamp": "136563265.81",
                             "Item_Weight_Process1_values": 0.2,
                             "Performance": 0.7
                         },
                         {
                             "Timestamp": "137563265.81",
                             "Item_Weight_Process1_values": 0.2,
                             "Performance": 1
                         }
                    ]
             }
```

I want to retrive all the unique values for Item_Weight_Process sorted with timpestamp. From the python by performing a find I am retrieving the following schema into a list. How can I filter that list?

**EDIT:** What I tried is the following:

```
for row in tbl:
    if row["Item_Weight_Process1_Value"] == 0.2:
        print row["Timestamp"]
```

This code returns the timpestamp for Item_Weight_Process1_Value = 0.2. I want to find the more recent one and then to return the correspondant performance.

Comment: What non-trivial attempts have you made so far?

Comment: I am not familiar on how I can retrieve the Item_Weight_Process from python and how i can sort the returned results on timestamp.

Comment: Which timestamp should be used for duplicate values?

Comment: I want to use the latest every time.

Comment: Put it in Mongo

Comment: Hey Erez, i didnt understand your question. The json is in mongo and I am retrieving it from python using the find function. No I want to return for a specific Item_Weight_Process1_values the more recent performance value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your structure is in variable tbl.

```
from operator import itemgetter
tbl = { ....


unique_weights = set ( [dico["Item_Weight_Process_values"] for dico in tbl["Item_Weight_Process"]] )


sorted_weights = sorted(tbl["Item_Weight_Process"], key=itemgetter("Timestamp"))

unique_sorted = []
for x in sorted_weights:
    if x["Item_Weight_Process_values"] not in unique_sorted:
        unique_sorted.append(x["Item_Weight_Process_values"])
```